# Elementary question subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Wondering about the difference here:

Let $E=(z \ \in C; Re(z)=0)$. Is it a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$-vecspace$\ \mathbb{C}$ and a subspace of $\mathbb{C}$-vecspace $\mathbb{C}$ ?

I easily show it is a subspace  but what does it change it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}-vecspace \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}-vecspace \mathbb{C}$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of an $\Bbb F$-vector space $V$:

1. $0 \in V$
2. For any $u, v \in V$, we have $u+v \in V$.
3. For any $f \in \Bbb F$ and $v \in V$, we have $f\cdot v \in V$.

It is the third point that really makes a difference for real vector spaces and complex vector spaces. We see that if $V$ is a $\Bbb C$-vector space, then for a vector $v\in V$, you have to have $(a+bi)\cdot v \in V$ for all real numbers $a, b$, while if $V$ is just supposed to be an $\Bbb R$-vector space, you only need to have $a\cdot v \in V$ for all real numbers $a$. Since $E$ consists of all complex numbers of the form $0 +bi$, we see that $(a'+b'i)\cdot (0+bi)$ is not usually an element of $E$, and it certainly isn't an element of $E$ for *all* real $a', b', b$, so $E$ is *not* a $\Bbb C$-vector space.

So any complex vector space is a real vector space, but not the other way around.